# Finding the sigma of a Gaussian array without using a fit

Tags: python, arrays, gaussian

I have an array, called `gaussian_array`, which is made of a series of numbers that, once plotted, form a Gaussian, to a good approximation.
I need to understand the `\sigma` of this Gaussian, but I am not allowed to use a fit of any kind. What I have tried so far is to calculate the peak of the Gaussian, which is given by the first element of the array (the Gaussian is centred around the origin), `gaussian_array[0]`, and then somehow I thought it could be useful to use the FWHM and the well known relation between `\sigma` and the FWHM.
However, I do not know exactly how to implement this in python. I thought it could have been useful to write something like

```
for i in range(len(gaussian_array)):
    if gaussian[i] = FWHM:
        sigma = gaussian[i]/(2.*np.sqrt(2.np.log(2)))
```

but I don't think that's a reliable procedure, because it will not always be true that a certain element of the `gaussian_array` will EXACTLY coincide to the calculated FWHM. I cannot even calculate the standard deviation by the sum of the squares of the differences between the values and the origin.
So, how could I estimate the `sigma` of this `gaussian_array`?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why you would go to such great lengths to calculate a standard deviation. In you post it seems you are trying to get the `\sigma` by this relation

[image]

If you are trying to obtain the standard deviation, just use numpy

```
import numpy as np

# method 1 - use np.std() on a python data structure
sigma = np.std(gaussian_array)    

# method 2 - convert to numpy array and use .std() method
gaussian_array = np.asarray(gaussian_array)
sigma = gaussian_array.std()
```